# Iterating a list present in an object in angular ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a controller defined as follows with the method getEmployeeDetails:

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('AppController',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.result = [];
    $scope.getEmployeeDetails = function() {
        var response = $http.get('http://localhost:8080/empMgt/employee/all');
        response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.result.push(data);
        });
        response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert( "Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
        });
    };

    $scope.getEmployeeDetails();
}]);
```

This method gets a result object in return that has a list of employees in it.
I am trying to show that list in a table in my html.

The html is as follows:

```
<body ng-controller="AppController" style="display:none">
    {{result}}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>EmployeeId</th>
            <th>ProjectId</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Employee Address</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="employee in result.listOfEntities">
            <td>{{employee.employeeId}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.projectId}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.employeeName}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.employeeAddress}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

The object comes fine in the html as i printed the same. The list is not getting iterated in the table row.

The returned data looks like this:

```
{
    "result": true,
    "resultCode": "SUCCESS",
    "listOfEntities": [{
        "employeeId": "1",
        "projectId": "1",
        "employeeName": "asdfg",
        "employeeAddress": "asdfg",
        "project": null
    }]
}
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you output what `data` variable contains ? Are you sure that `listOfEntities` it's in `data` object ?

Comment: Could you post a sample of the objects in `result`?

Comment: @PrerakSola I'm trying to iterate over listOfEntities..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result.listOfEntities` does not exist, beacause `result` is clearly an array:

```
$scope.result = [];
$scope.result.push(data);
```

I imagine you would be better off without the array, and instead:

```
$scope.result = data;
```

or even:

```
$scope.listOfEntities = data.listOfEntities;
ng-repeat="employee in listOfEntities"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `$scope.result` as an array(`$scope.result=[]`). So `result.listOfEntites` will not resolve to anything. As per your sample data, it should be an object (`$scope.result={};`) and in the response from your server, you should do `$scope.result = data`

Answer (score 0):

Why you are use push.. We don't need to push, We can use directly.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('AppController', [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.result = [];
$scope.getEmployeeDetails = function() {            
  var data = {
    "result": true,
    "resultCode": "SUCCESS",
    "listOfEntities": [{
        "employeeId": "1",
        "projectId": "1",
        "employeeName": "asdfg",
        "employeeAddress": "asdfg",
        "project": null
    }]
  };
  $scope.result.push(data.listOfEntities[0]);
};
$scope.getEmployeeDetails();
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">
    <div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
        <!-- Main content -->
        <div class="program-section">
            {{result.listOfEntities}}
            <div class="container">
                <table class="table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>EmployeeId</th>
                        <th>ProjectId</th>
                        <th>Employee Name</th>
                        <th>Employee Address</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="employee in result">{{employee}}
                        <td>{{employee.employeeId}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.projectId}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.employeeName}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.employeeAddress}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./program-section -->
    </div>
    <!-- ./wrapper -->
</body>
```